# Приложение не видит базу данных после сборки в exe

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Собрал приложение на C# WPF с подключением к базе данных sql.
При компиляции в Visual Studio все работает хорошо, но при запуске exe файла взаимодействие с базой пропадает
Стоит полноценный SQL Server. Подключение через ADO.NET
Обращался к полям бд через экземпляр базы данных "Entities"
Как можно это починить?

Comment: У вас же конфиг файл в той же папке, где вы exe запускаете? Покажите строку подключения в собранном приложении.